# htmlentities returning blank after upgrading to PHP 5.5

Tags: php, html-entities, php-5.5

After upgrading to PHP 5.5, html_entities is returning blank for some strings. Specifically, it seems to be strings that contain French characters. I have tried setting it to UTF-8 but still blank:

```
htmlentities($str,ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Anybody know what's going on here?

My code was working without issue on PHP 5.3.3.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Example string from comment

```
"<h1>Obtenez de meilleurs résultats en moins de temps. Garanti.</h1>"
```

Comment: Can you provide the value of `$str` so we can try and replicate?

Comment: might be something else. If you're using deprecated functions, that could be it and `$str` is failing. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - are you using this with a DB and `mysql_` by any chance with this? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Here's a string: "<h1>Obtenez de meilleurs résultats en moins de temps. Garanti.</h1>"

Comment: if you have any further info, please post it in your question and not in comments. I asked you something in my comment up there. There could be relevance here and posting exact code used.

Comment: On the face of it, it seems to work fine. https://3v4l.org/0BYsM

Comment: consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through-mysql-php-and-html and read all of that.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me too. I tested on [PHP Tester](http://phptester.net/) using PHP v5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

> If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set.

so something like

```
<?php
$str = "<h1>\xe2 title</h1>";
echo htmlentities($str,ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

see https://3v4l.org/9OuRE

will return an empty string